# How to open ubuntu calculator programming mode

Tags: ubuntu, calculator

I need to do some calculations in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS calculator's programming mode. Whenever I open the default calculator via the GUI it opens in basic mode and there are no options to switch to programming mode.

[image: No programming mode drop-down menu]

I managed to start it from terminal with

```
sudo gnome-calculator
```

but then terminal goes into kind of a text editor mode (which I don't want) and if I stop the text editing mode with CTRL+z calculator hangs.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the modes are listed in the **mode** tab.

This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233387/how-do-i-use-the-scientific-mode-in-the-calculator) details it better.

Comment: dam! thank you a lot! I hadn't noticed that in Ubunto some options are on the top line of the screen!

Comment: With pleasure. I don't know how to do that, this is my 2nd question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ah okay. The it would be good to take the tour for people starting using stackoverflow and stack exchange in general. To accept an answer just click on the tick below the score of the answer.

Comment: Mate I have reputation 6, and voting and marking closed is not allowed to me.

Comment: what? I didn't understand.

Comment: Accept an answer is to click the tick below the answer score  so it turns green. Maybe you should take the stackoverflow tour to see how the website works.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I found it! 

Comment: I was searching near my question 